# How to know if multiple arrays in a list are the same

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare, comparison

I would like to know whether all arrays within a list are the same.
`==` compares two arrays, but I want to know if there is any library method to tell if all arrays within a list are the same.

Comment: @orde Not sure that could possibly help with this particular question.

Comment: @takendarkk.  from http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve: "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.".

Comment: Exactly, and the problem is not caused by code the OP has written. That's the whole point of the question being asked - what code can be used...

Comment: When the elements of the array `arr` are comparable you can write 'arr.max == 'arr.min`.

Comment: @orde, so far as I know there is no SO policy that requires askers to post code, even though people ask for it all the time (except when the asker is obviously experienced, in which case they are *never* asked, which strikes me as a bit of a double standard). If the question is homework, the asker is expected to explain what efforts he or she has made to solve the problem, but even then the production of code is not a requirement. Often, the OP does not present code because they haven't a clue where to begin. Do we really want to force askers to present code even if it's gibberish?

Comment: @Cary: Understood.  I probably shouldn't have been so blunt.  My point was that questions with code--and a demonstrated effort to solve a problem--will get better answers.  Moving on :)

Comment: @orde, or, if the code is gibberish, more downvotes. -:) In my experience, the attention that is given to a question depends mainly on the number of readers that find the question unambiguous and interesting.

Comment: Code isn't necessarily the most important criteria, effort is. Code is often used as an indicator of the effort put into solving the problem, however a review of the searches used and why they were not useful can also indicate there was effort. In this case, there is no evidence of effort; Ruby's Enumerable or Array documentation would have revealed several methods that could help solve the problem, at which a little code testing would have answered the question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is related. And down voting for lack of research is a possiblility.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the list of arrays just once, **comparing the first array with all the other arrays**. If the first one is equal to all the others, then all arrays in the list are equal. Something like this will work:

```
arrays = [[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]]
array0 = arrays.first
arrays[1..-1].all? { |a| array0 == a }
# => true

arrays = [[1,3],[1,3],[1,4]]
array0 = arrays.first
arrays[1..-1].all? { |a| array0 == a }
# => false
```

Comment: You'll gain a bit of speed by moving `arr.first` outside the block and assigning it to a variable that's accessed inside the block. `ary0 = arr.first; ...`

Comment: Thanks, @Tin Man, you are right, I'll update the answer. Overall, I am curious about the relative performance / memory footprint of each of the answers here, perhaps I'll do some tests.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about the performance of each of the solutions here. Please be welcome to edit this post with your own results, if you like.

In my tests, the difference between the approaches raised with the length of the list of arrays, so I preferably measured a long list of relatively short arrays. I always did a few runs to remove the possible influence of GC.

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10
n_arrays = 1000000
arrays = [(1..n).to_a] * n_arrays

Benchmark.bm(14) do |bm|
  bm.report("1st vs others:") do
    array0 = arrays.first
    arrays[1..-1].all? { |a| array0 == a }
  end

  bm.report("uniq:") { arrays.uniq.size == 1 }
  bm.report("each_cons:") { arrays.each_cons(2).all?{|x, y| x == y}  }
end
```

The results suggest that while the `each_cons` approach is about the same (only slightly slower) than the "1st vs others" approach, the one using `uniq` is much much slower.

```
                  user     system      total        real
1st vs others:   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.080872)
uniq:            1.810000   0.000000   1.810000 (  1.807646)
each_cons:       0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.174251)
```

Comment: Look into [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity). It is a good tool for benchmarking and results in more usable information more easily. Benchmark is good but you have to be aware of too many things that can affect the results. Also, it's good to test alternate input scenarios, for instance, add a condition causing a false result at the start or end of the array being checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]].uniq.size == 1
  #=> true

[[1,3],[1,3],[1,4]].uniq.size == 1
  #=> false
```

Comment: Although I like you approach the best, visually, it seems to be by far the slowest one, see my answer for details.

Comment: Although [the proof of the pudding is in the eating](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_proof_of_the_pudding_is_in_the_eating),  I would expect my solution to be relatively slow when confirming that not all elements of an array are equal (as it traverses the entire array, whereas approaches such as yours stop as soon as two unequal elements have been found). If all elements are equal (meaning that all methods must traverse the entire array), I would expect `uniq` (written in C) to be reasonably fast. No?

Comment: Well, that is why I bencharked equal arrays and still uniq was orders of magnitude slower (see above for numbers). I have no idea why but the difference looked very consistent. But overall I agree that such testing is artificial.

Comment: @BoraMa, I wrote my previous comment on a phone. I didn't see any benchmarking in your answer and didn't scroll down and discover you put the pudding in a separate answer. I have no explanation for why`uniq` did so poorly. btw, I was not questioning the value of benchmarking.

Comment: aha, I see now, I put it in a separate answer as it seemed too unrelated to my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.each_cons(2).all?{|x, y| x == y}
```

Comment: Could you add a description of how this code answers the question? It works, yes, and it's obvious to someone who's used the language, but it's better to teach people instead of letting them copy/paste all the time.